# iPad app development on Windows

Tags: windows-7, development, ipad

Is there anyway you can develop iPad applications on Windows? I know there must be but can't seem to find an appropriate IDE. [Apps using HTML 5, CSS 3 and Javascript]

Comment: having to buy a mac is the least of your problem, you also need to learn objective c (that only apple uses these days).

Comment: I'm kinda learning objective C (Cocoa) now so thats not really a problem :) but the apps I wanna make are centered around html5, css3 and js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple only officially supports iOS development on a mac.  As a work around, you can build a web app using your preferred web development suite, try to get away with something like [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/), or you can try to get OS X to install in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are probably into HTML, JS and CSS, then Adobe Air would support you to deploy an app for iPhone and iPad. Adobe air uses a combination of ActionScript, HTML, CSS and Javascript to build applications.